# PHP Form Submits automatically at page load

Tags: php

My PHP form submits automatically when my page loads. When it submits automatically, my SQL data base register a form submission but with no data recollected.

Not sure how to get it fix.

This is my code.

```
<?php 
    //connection to database
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","subscriber","password","data-Base");

    $emailErr = "";
    $email = "";
    $Email = $_POST['email'];

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "Email is required";
      } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
          $emailErr = "Please enter a Valid Email"; 
        }
      }
    }
    //form submission
    $sql = "INSERT INTO emails (Email) VALUES ('$Email')";
?>
<?php
    // define variables and set to empty values
    function test_input($data) {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      return $data;
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
    if($email){
        $sent = "Thank You for Subscribing";
}
?>

<form id="login" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?
>" method="post">

    <fieldset id="inputs">
        <input id="username" name="email" type="text" 
        placeholder="Sign up for our newsletter:">    
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="actions">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Subscribe">
    </fieldset>

       <div class="email-sent">
            <?php if(!empty($sent)) { echo $sent; } ?> <br>
            <?php echo $emailErr;?>
       </div>
</form>
```

Comment: what do you mean `black data recorded taking a row`?

Comment: I had a misspell, I meant that no data was recollected. My SQL database will show that a form was submitted and a row will appear with no data. I added the form that I am sussing to collect my data.

Comment: where variable `$sql` is actually used?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because that's what you're telling it to do. Wrap it in an isset submit. Ideally I'd put your tests in that as well, I'll show after, and give it an error count, if error == 0, then submit.

```
<?php 
    //connection to database
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","subscriber","password","data-Base");
    //if we fail to connect

    $emailErr = "";
    $email = "";
    $Email = $_POST['email'];
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "Email is required";
      } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
          $emailErr = "Please enter a Valid Email"; 
        }
      }
    }
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //form submission
    $sql = "INSERT INTO emails (Email) VALUES ('$Email')";
}
?>
<?php
    // define variables and set to empty values
    function test_input($data) {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      return $data;
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
    if($email){
        $sent = "Thank You for Subscribing";
}
?>

<form id="login" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?
>" method="post">
```

Better method, wrap it all in an isset and then validate using an error count

```
<?php 
    //connection to database
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","subscriber","password","data-Base");
    //if we fail to connect

    $emailErr = "";
    $email = "";
    $Email = $_POST['email'];

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$errorCount = 0;


      if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "Email is required";
        $errorCount++;
      }

      $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
      // check if e-mail address is well-formed
      if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $emailErr = "Please enter a Valid Email"; 
        $errorCount++;
      }

    if($errorCount == 0){
     //form submission
      $sql = "INSERT INTO emails (Email) VALUES ('$Email')";
    }

}
?>
<?php
    // define variables and set to empty values
    function test_input($data) {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      return $data;
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
    if($email){
        $sent = "Thank You for Subscribing";
}
?>

<form id="login" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?
>" method="post">
```

Comment: what is the sense of wraping variable declaration?

Comment: It's not wrapping the declaration, the first method only wrapped the insert into @Lashane

Comment: what is the sense of wraping variable declaration? your code just wrapped initialization of unused variable `$sql`

Comment: How do you know there's a field or button with a `name="submit"` in the form?

Comment: His code isn't complete but that would stop faulty submission. He's currently just running it upon load of the page

Comment: All he has to do is move his INSERT query one line up, so that it's inside his existing `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {` check.

Comment: I added the form that I am using to collect the emails for our newsletter subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Stuff it all into a check, no need to query anything if nothing is submitted, if submitted than do it.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","subscriber","password","data-Base");

    $emailErr = "";
    $email = "";
    $Email = $_POST['email'];
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "Email is required";
      } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
          $emailErr = "Please enter a Valid Email"; 
        }
      }
    }
    //form submission
    $sql = "INSERT INTO emails (Email) VALUES ('$Email')";
}
?>
<form action="">
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Alternatively, if say you have multiple forms on one page, you can identify which submit button is pushed and act accordingly. In which case you would want to move you `$con` out on its own and not in that block, otherwise you'd have to add it to each one..

```
<?php 
if($_POST['submit'] == 'email_submit'){
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","subscriber","password","data-Base");

    $emailErr = "";
    $email = "";
    $Email = $_POST['email'];
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "Email is required";
      } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
          $emailErr = "Please enter a Valid Email"; 
        }
      }
    }
    //form submission
    $sql = "INSERT INTO emails (Email) VALUES ('$Email')";
}
?>
<form action="">
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <button type="submit" value="submit" value="email_submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

That should work, but as always, no promises :)